# Unobtrusive, realtime notifications of new RSS entries

Tags: rss, real-time

First, why I ask:  Now that reputation points on StackOverflow have real value (you can spend them on damn good answers by offering bounties) I'd like to monitor questions I might be able to answer and pounce on them!  (Also the fact that others answer my questions in real time makes StackOverflow amazingly handy, so it would be nice to reciprocate.)

To ask this as a more general question, not specific to StackOverflow:

- What kind of delay will there typically be in an RSS feed vs polling and scraping?
- What's a good way to display the notifications in a not-too-distracting way, such as Growl on Mac?  (It should also be easy to turn on and off, if it does get too distracting.)

(Or, for StackOverflow addicts, what's your setup for pouncing on new questions and can you generalize it for monitoring other web content in real time?)

Comment: This illustrates the number one reason why the tubes are clogged. Also, my god, pouncing on questions, what is this, some kind of bloody game?

Comment: Are the tubes clogged?  I encourage you to post an answer that includes throttling guidelines; that would be a great public service.  As for whether this is a game and whether it's bloody: I suppose, but getting realtime answers really does make this an amazing resource!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What kind of delay will there
>   typically be in an RSS feed vs polling
>   and scraping?

That depends on what sort of caching the site uses for its RSS feed. On SO there is no noticeable delay on most feeds, but you will need to poll the feed every minute or so. A program can not automagically get notifications from the site itself unless there is some sort of ping service on site in question.

Comment: I was happy to vote this question as helpful, but, just for the record and with all respect to Espo, I disavow this as the "accepted answer". (It was auto-chosen by the bounty system.)

Comment: The great news is the StackOverflow supports PubSubHubbub, so if you use any tool that supports it too, that will be instantaneous.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the service at [notify.me](http://notify.me) as a slightly more obtrusive version of an RSS reader.  It monitors a feed and sends you e-mail alerts.  But with the basic StackOverflow setup you'd probably be overwhelmed by notifications even if there were just a "questions with bounties" feed, because there are many bounty offers per day.

So maybe combine that with [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) and build a filtered subset based on the information that only contain subjects you're interested in answering.  Each entry in the SO RSS feed has a "category" node which contains all of its tags, and Pipes would allow you to build AND / OR / NOT expressions based on those categories.  (and I don't know what other attributes might be exposed?)

Even if you don't want the pop-up notifications you get with e-mail, the Pipes solution will let you monitor what you want in an RSS feed.  I'd guess that you'd see about an hour or two of lag, though.

Comment: Thanks; great answer!  I'm not sure it would be so bad to see the stream of StackOverflow questions in real time, especially if you only had it visible when you were reading blogs or otherwise out of the zone.

Answer (score 2):

In regards to question #1:

Make it as short as you like. If whatever you are using to get the feed correctly supports [ETags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) and [HTTP Cache-Control](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#CACHE-CONTROL) you should be fine. If you control both the server and the client, maybe checking out [Delta Encoding](http://www.wyman.us/main/2004/09/using_rfc3229_w.html) ([RFC 3229](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3229.txt)) would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Butcher an open source  reader to turn on/blink your scroll lock LED.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a tcp-style backoff to handle feed polling. The more often someone posts, the more often you poll.

Google reader does this; the more I post on my blog, the faster each post shows up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm experimenting with Feed Notifier for this purpose.

http://www.feednotifier.com/

I'm still not able to pounce, per se, as I will get my popups several minutes late. At that point, they've already got 30 viewers, 3 answers, etc.

So I'd love to see the answer to secondary question....

Answer (score 0):

The [Vienna RSS Reader](http://www.vienna-rss.org) for Mac shows Growl notifications, but only of the form "X new messages" and not very realtime.

Answer (score 0):

VibeFire is a decent solution for this.  It'll read RSS feeds and pop up notifications (that will automatically go away if you don't read them) for you.  http://vibefire.com if you're interested.  Its a bundled installer though, but it won't install anything you don't accept.